# python + argparse - how to get order of optional arguments from command line

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to know how to get order of optional argument passed from commandline to argparse

I have image processing class which is able to apply different actions to image - like rotate, crop, resize...

And order in which these actions are applied is often essential (for example: you want to crop image before you resize it)

I have this code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Image processing arguments')

parser.add_argument('source_file', help='source file')
parser.add_argument('target_file', help='target file')

parser.add_argument('-resize', nargs=2, help='resize image', metavar=('WIDTH', 'HEIGHT'))
parser.add_argument('-rotate', nargs=1, help='rotate image', metavar='ANGLE')
parser.add_argument('-crop', nargs=4, help='crop image', metavar=('START_X','START_Y','WIDTH','HEIGHT'))

ar = parser.parse_args()

print ar
```

But - no matter in which order I pass parameters to script:

**cmd.py test.jpg test2.jpg -crop 10 10 200 200 -resize 450 300**

**cmd.py test.jpg test2.jpg -resize 450 300 -crop 10 10 200 200**

in Namespace items are always in same order (alphabetical I suppose):

```
Namespace(crop=['10', '10', '200', '200'], resize=['450', '300'], rotate=None, source_file='test.jpg', target_file='test
2.jpg')
```

Is there way to order them by position in command line string or to get their index?

Answer (score 6):

You could always peek at `sys.argv` which is a list (and thus ordered) and simply iterate over it checking which argument comes first or use the `list.index()` to see the respective positions of your keywords in the list...

`sys.argv` contains a list of the words entered in the command line (the delimiter of such "word" is a space unless a string was surrounded by quotation marks). This means that if the user entered something like `./my_proggie -resize 500` then `sys.argv` would contain a list like this: `['./my_proggie', '-resize', '500']`.

Answer (score 5):

The Namespace is a simple object whose `str()` lists its attributes according to the order of the keys in its `__dict__`.  Attributes are set with `setattr(namespace, dest, value)`.

One solution is to define a custom Namespace class.  For example:

```
class OrderNamespace(argparse.Namespace):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__['order'] = []
        super(OrderNamespace, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        self.__dict__['order'].append(attr)
        super(OrderNamespace, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
```

and use

```
args = parser.parse_args(None, OrderNamespace())
```

producing for your two examples

```
OrderNamespace(crop=..., order=[..., 'crop', 'resize'], resize=...)
OrderNamespace(crop=..., order=[..., 'resize', 'crop'], resize=...)
```

The `order` attribute gives the order in which the other attributes are set.  The initial items are for defaults and the file positionals. Adding `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` to the arguments will suppress some of these items.  This custom class could be more elaborate, using for example an OrderedDictionary, only noting the order for selected arguments, or using `order` to control the display of the attributes.

Another option is to use a custom Action class that creates this `order` attribute, e.g.

```
class OrderAction(argparse._StoreAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
        order = getattr(namespace, 'order') if hasattr(namespace, 'order') else []
        order.append(self.dest)
        setattr(namespace, 'order', order)
```

Comment: OrderNamespace is a great solution if one also wants to use another actions (e.g. builtins). Great idea!

Comment: Unfortunately when default values are set, the `__setattr__` method is called for all default values, nevertheless they were used or not.

Comment: If you don't use `SUPPRESS` defaults will appear at the start of the 'order' list, and maybe again at the end.  The `parser` uses the same `__setattr__` to record defaults and given values.  The `OrderAction` does not have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I adapted the approach from hpaulj:

```
    class OrderNamespace(argparse.Namespace):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.__dict__['order'] = []
            super(OrderNamespace, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
            if value:
              self.__dict__['order'].append(attr)
            super(OrderNamespace, self).__setattr__(attr, value)


    parser.add_argument('-g',action='append',default=argparse.SUPPRESS,help='some action')
```

By adding the "if value:" ... you only get every used argument the correct number of times.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with [@Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8895443/martin) 's solution: it does not work with cases like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--slong', action='store_false')
```

Here is my solution:

```
import argparse

class OrderedNamespace(argparse.Namespace):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__["_order"] = []
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        super().__setattr__(attr, value)
        if attr in self._order:
            self.__dict__["_order"].clear()
        self.__dict__["_order"].append(attr)
    def ordered(self):
        return ((attr, getattr(self, attr)) for attr in self._order)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--test1', default=1)
parser.add_argument('--test2')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--slong', action='store_false')
parser.add_argument('--test3', default=3)

args = parser.parse_args(['--test2', '2', '--test1', '1', '-s'], namespace=OrderedNamespace())

print(args)
print(args.test1)
for a, v in args.ordered():
    print(a, v)
```

Output is:

```
OrderedNamespace(_order=['test2', 'test1', 'slong'], slong=False, test1='1', test2='2', test3=3)
1
test2 2
test1 1
slong False
```